# Renaming files with last modified time on file name

Tags: command-line, mv

I am trying to rename a file with the `mv` command and I would like to add the last modified date of this file (with YYYYMMDD format) on the file name and move it to other folder. I got the current system date like this:

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/a.txt "/home/user/Desktop/testfolder/$(date +%Y%m%d)-a.txt"
```

I used other combinations of `date` but I didn't get it. I need to know if it is possible do it directly by command line or I need to create a script.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this command:

```
mv /dir_path/example.txt /new_dir_path/$(date +%Y-%m-%d -r example.txt)example.txt
```

Comment: Yes the command "date +%Y-%m-%d -r example.txt" gives last modified date of a file.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to get things correct with a small script file.

-o-

I think you want to use the modification date instead of the current date, see the output from

```
ls -l a.txt
```

or

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got it! Only one detail. If you are using the command from a path where the original file is not, you need to use this:

mv /dir_path/example.txt /new_dir_path/$(date +%Y-%m-%d -r /dir_path/example.txt)example.txt